# Which authentication should be used for external users (not registered with the system)

Tags: security, authentication, web-api, asp.net-core

I'm working with a project that uses ASP.NET Core 2.2. The main solution contains different projects, including APIs for a mobile application, APIs to integrate the system with third parties, a web application, etc.

1. Mobile API - For internal application
2. Public API - To integrate our system with others
3. Web - Website

We're using token-based authentication for mobile API project. However, to expose our Public APIs for third parties, we don't want to use token-based authentication, instead, we decided to use the key - secret.

But the issue is that another project *(integration to use our system internally)* has its registered users and they don't want to create an account in our system. I suspect that, in this case, key-secret things wouldn't work. We currently use api-key for every project(tenant), and they have to keep api-key for their users. However, this could create security issues if we expose API endpoints publicly.

Along with this, we'd like to track request per user too.

What type of authentication solves this problem? and how can we handle such a scenario?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54260837/multiple-authentication-methods-in-asp-net-core-2-2

Comment: Thanks @Ewan! but the pinned question wanted to use JWT authentication in a custom way, however, in this case, I ask about best fit authentication approach.

Comment: `However, to expose our Public APIs for third parties, we don't want to use token-based authentication, ` Why?

Comment: `We currently use api-key for every project(tenant), and they have to keep api-key for their users. However, this could create security issues if we expose API endpoints publicly.` How could create security issues?

Comment: @Laiv, *Why* Because token based authentication meaningful when users have registered with your system, you authenticate them and issue a token.

Comment: But you said they already have an API-Key per user. That's their "authentication". In the worse case, you could simply generate the API key for them instead of forcing a registration. You just supply the API Key. This way you know who have keys all the time.

Comment: @Laiv: Sorry for the confusion. It's a multi-tenant application and *We currently uses api-key for every project(tenant)*

Comment: That's ok and for the sake of the multitenancy you should not change the rules now or the economy of scale starts to blur.

Comment: @Laiv, *How could create security issues?* The api-key passes in the header of every request, I believe, if someone would catch the header in-between, can call the server and get the data easily. Make me correct if I'm wrong

Comment: @Div the question I linked to essentially has the same problem. they want to use more than one auth scheme. You can do this, but its fiddly

Comment: Most public APIs I know of use OAuth 2.0 for system to system integration.  The key is negotiated between the two systems with the user's complicit set up so that the key is tied to that user.  This allows you to add tweets on behalf of that user, or create Facebook posts on behalf of the user without ever asking them to re-enter there credentials.